# Using a name spaced JQuery with Isotope on site running multiple JQ breaks browser resize function

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

GlobalPost is very excited to use Isotope for our new business page.

http://www.globalpost.com/business-news

We run on Drupal and thus already have an old version of jquery running on each page.

I namespaced the new JQ like so on the page

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/all/themes/globalpost_3/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>    
<script type='text/javascript'>
  // added to run both jquery releases on page and stop conflist with old JQ libraray
 var jQuery_1_7_1 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/all/themes/globalpost_3/js/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/all/themes/globalpost_3/js/gp5_biz.js"></script>
```

and edited the min version of isitope like so at the end

```
....eturn this}})(window,jQuery_1_7_1);
```

It load fine and runs fine as you can see, BUT if you resize the window the blocks don't reflow. If you chose a filter or sort they do, but not or window resize. I looked long at your code but just can't seem to figure out what could be causing the issue or how to fix it.

I must name space the jq library to avoid conflicts but resizing worked fine before I did. I 'm sure other will need to use a name spaced JQ with Isotope.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you tried upgrading isotope to v1.5.19? I recreated your issue with your minified v1.5.17 code, and then when I changed to v1.5.19 (unminified) everything is flowing correctly.

Comment: I had not tried that but after you suggestion I did. There was no change as you can see here. http://web3.globalpost.com/business-news

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Where (and how) do you initialize isotope? It may have to do with the jquery that is being referenced. I did it like this:

```
var jQuery171 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
jQuery171(function(){
    var $container = jQuery171("#container");
    $container.isotope({
        itemSelector: ".element"
    });
});
```

Comment: You last comment made me take another look at how we included the new jquery library and really the old library as well. I started to think perhaps the older library was the bad actor here. and since it get included in the main batch of js files I can't access it directly to give it a specific name space.

I had an Idea to basically let the old JQ library basically do all it's work them name space it out of the way, like so.

Answer (score 0):

You last comment made me take another look at how we included the new jquery library and really the old library as well. I started to think perhaps the older library was the bad actor here and since it get included in the main batch of js files(the Drupal system) I can't access it directly to give it a specific name space. It would also be hell to go through and re-namespace all the native jq functions.

I had an Idea to basically let the old JQ library basically do all it's work them name space it out of the way, like so.

```
<?php print $scripts; ?> <!-- all the JS for the site including old 1.3.2 JQuery -->

<script type="text/javascript">
  var jQuery132 = $.noConflict(true); // Kill the old JQ now that it is done with initializing old script
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/all/themes/globalpost_3/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>    <!-- load shinny new JQuery which takes over $ and jQuery name space -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/all/themes/globalpost_3/js/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>   <!-- non name spaced libs using default $ -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/all/themes/globalpost_3/js/gp5_biz.js"></script>
```

Is this the best way ever, maybe not but it works.

Thank you so much for spending you precious time helping me work through this. I'm sending good Karma your way.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback! Glad to help out - Isotope is a cool plugin. Be sure to mark my answer as the answer too - that helps.